# gojs append child node between node on different level

Tags: javascript, jquery, gojs

I am using goJS code that is exactly same as this link page [gojs](http://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartEditor.html). I am trying to add a node that is located between 2 nodes.

For example like picture below
[image: images]

As we can see, corporate secretary and corporate manager is located between president & VP Corporate Services. However, it doesn't mean both of them are the same level as VP Corporate services.Is it possible to implement this in gojs?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is an example: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartAssistants.html.  This example is derived from the [Org Chart sample](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/orgChartStatic.html) of [GoJS](https://gojs.net).

This defines a `SideTreeLayout` that supports having subtrees "on the side" above the regular children of a node.  Customize the `isAssistant` predicate to determine whether a node should be a "side" node or not.

Such functionality might be more than you need.  You did not indicate whether you needed to support subtrees on the side rather than just individual nodes.